# Single SOQL query for Accounts without Contacts

Tags: apex, soql, inner-join

How to query those Account which has not any related Contacts ? I have  Queried Account and contact in inner query. I found All Account with that Account I looped and find those Account whose Contact equals Null. But I want, can it be acheive by query only no need to loop over Acccout . Please Help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This query will give you accounts that **DO NOT** have any contacts.

```
Select Id, Name From Account Where Id NOT IN (Select AccountId From Contact)
```

On the flip, you can query all Accounts that do **have at least 1 contact** like this

```
Select Id, Name From Account Where Id IN (Select AccountId From Contact)
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help  :)